# Second dropdown button in navigation bar showing the same content as the previous button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

My first dropdown button "Content" works correctly but when I click on the second dropdown button "Dropdown", the contents from the first dropdown button show up instead???

I have no idea why it is doing this??? Maybe I am overlooking a small detail, but I can't seem to find where I am going wrong with this.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rosybrown
}

#titleNav {
  z-index: 2;
  /* added for fixed layout: keeps titleNav on top of other elemements */
  position: fixed;
  /* added for fixed layout */
  top: 0px;
  /* added for fixed layout */
  left: 0px;
  /* added for fixed layout */
  width: 100%;
  /* added for fixed layout */
  background-color: white;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 600px;
  /* prevents nav links from wrapping when browser window is too narrow */
}

#title {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 22%;
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  text-align: justify;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 150%;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.image:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#footer {
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.89);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0xp;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.stopFloat {
  clear: both;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JS Framework</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="titleNav">
    <div id="title">
      <img src="pics/logo.png" width="160" height="39" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Content
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
          <a onclick="makeFramework('contentId', 'aboutUs.html');">About Us</a>
          <a onclick="makeFramework('contentId', 'aboutCoffee.html');">Coffee</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="../labs.html">Labs</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="contentId">
    Content Area
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    Web footer
  </div>

  <script src="framework.js"></script>
  <script src="dropDownMenu.js"></script>
  <script>
    "use strict";

    makeFramework('contentId', 'aboutUs.html');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **ID's** should be unique and not used for multiple elements. For grouping elements you should use a `class` name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ummm.... because you call the same function from both buttons.

Essentially, you run the same piece of code, `myFunction`, despite which navigation item is clicked. Therefore, of course both items will always do the same thing.

Give each menu a different ID (remember that IDs need to be *unique* - i.e. you can't have two items with the same ID), and make `myFunction` take the ID of the element to show / hide, as shown below.

This means that there is a way for the function to determine which menu open, and thus it will open the correct one.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onmouseup = function(e) {
  var dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown-content.show"); //Get any shown dropdown element (i.e. any element on the page with both the dropdown-content class and the show class
  if (dropdown) { //If such an element exists, a dropdown needs to be closed
    dropdown.classList.remove("show"); //So remove the show class
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rosybrown
}

#titleNav {
  z-index: 2;
  /* added for fixed layout: keeps titleNav on top of other elemements */
  position: fixed;
  /* added for fixed layout */
  top: 0px;
  /* added for fixed layout */
  left: 0px;
  /* added for fixed layout */
  width: 100%;
  /* added for fixed layout */
  background-color: white;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 600px;
  /* prevents nav links from wrapping when browser window is too narrow */
}

#title {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 22%;
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  text-align: justify;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 150%;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.image:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#footer {
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.89);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0xp;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.stopFloat {
  clear: both;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JS Framework</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="titleNav">
    <div id="title">
      <img src="pics/logo.png" width="160" height="39" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction('dropdownOne')">Content
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdownOne">
          <a onclick="makeFramework('contentId', 'aboutUs.html');">About Us</a>
          <a onclick="makeFramework('contentId', 'aboutCoffee.html');">Coffee</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction('dropdownTwo')">Dropdown
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdownTwo">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="../labs.html">Labs</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="contentId">
    Content Area
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    Web footer
  </div>

  <script src="framework.js"></script>
  <script src="dropDownMenu.js"></script>
  <script>
    "use strict";

    makeFramework('contentId', 'aboutUs.html');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

## How does this work?

`myFunction('dropdownOne')` means that the `id` variable in `myFunction` is  given the value `dropdownOne` - therefore when we call `document.getElementById(id)` it will interpret as `document.getElementById('dropdownOne')` instead, and hence the first dropdown is targeted.

Likewise, if we call `myFunction('dropdownTwo')`, then it will interpret as `document.getElementById('dropdownTwo')`, and thus target the second dropdown.

Therefore, you can add as many menu items like this as you want, assuming each has a unique identifier, and `myFunction` is given the unique ID each time.

Comment: this works but when I go look at the show Page source I get an error saying TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'myDropdown.classList')

Comment: @pyuntae Sorry, somehow missed that part of your code. All fixed now :D